# Weird add many Char in javascript

Tags: javascript

Today i saw an example of JavaScript and i can not understand it.

```
('b' + 'a' + + 'a' + 'a').toLowerCase()
```

**result:** `"banana"`

I don't understand it, why JavaScript add 2 'n' between each 'a'?

Comment: consider the value `NaN` (remove toLowerCase to reveal this) ... the middle `a` becomes *not a number*

Comment: Why down vote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `‘b’` and `‘a’` are simply strings being added as `‘ba’`. After the second `‘a’`, you see a double plus sign(+), the first one is for concatenation like the previous plus sign. But the second plus sign is called the unary operator which simply transforms the string into a number, if it isn’t already. Since ‘a’ cannot be converted to a number it is converted to `‘NaN’`. The final ‘a’ is added to this `‘baNaN’` string and the final `‘baNaNa’` string is made. And to finish it up, the toLowerCase function is used and the output `‘banana’` is received.